# 'finish' or 'have finished'

Tags: tense

I would like to know if the word ***finish*** could be replaced by ***have finished***. Is there a difference? Thanks.

> Until you finish all your food, you cannot go out and play.

Answer (score 1):

In that particular context (and most others), yes, you could easily use 'have finished' in place of 'finish'.

However, be aware that there are a few exceptions - a 'finish line', for example, or the other meaning of 'finish':

> the surface coating or texture of wood, metal, etc.

'Have finished' doesn't make sense in those situations.